# activeX component in axapta

Tags: dll, activex, axapta

i'm struggling with an .net activeX i try to use in ms axapta 2009.

using this component on my local machine where it was compiled, it's working quite fine.
it can be added as activeX element on a form, the methods and events are listed in the axapta-activeX-explorer and i can interact with it without any problems.

but trying to distribute the dll to other clients isn't working as intended.
the registration of the dll via regasm /codebase /tlb  works properly - getting the message, registration was successful.
the component is also listed when selecting an activeX-element to add in ax, but neither functions nor properties are listed. and launching the form results in an errormessage - activeX component CLSID ... not found on system, not installed. the classID is indeed the one, defined in .net.

strange things happen, having a look on the task-manager. the activeX-component itself is just a wrapper to interact with a com-application. when launching the ax-form with the *not working* and _not_installed_!! activeX-thing, the taskmanager shows a new process of the com-application, which is instanciated by the activeX :/

things i tried:

- using different versions of regasm, eg \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 ; 
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
- using new GUIDs in .net, prior removing the old ones from the registry
- compiling, using different versions of the .net framework
- doing registration via regasm, regasm /codebase, regasm /codebase /tlb, using a visual-studio-setup
- running registration via command-line as administrator
- running setup as administrator
- running even ax as administrator on client-machine
- moving dll to a different folder followed by new registration ( windows/system32; ax/client/bin )
- installing to GAC ( gacutil /i  )
- different project-options in visual studio ( COM-Visibility; register for COM-Interop; different targetPlatform )

hoped for the fact, that compiling in visual studio with register for COM-Interop option enabled does something more than just the regasm-registration, i used a registry-monitor-microsoft-tool for logging the registry-activity which happend during compilation.

using these logs to create all registry-entries on the target-client in addition didn't work either.

any hints or help would be so much appreciated!
this thing is blocking me for days now :(

Comment: Why are you accessing the .Net component through a COM interface instead of CLR access directly?
Have you tried access through registering in AOT\References?
Have you tried regsvr32 to register the DLL (Regasm should do the job).
Regsvr32 is used to register COM/ActiveX components.

Comment: Try to specify the exact error message.

Comment: Why the ActiveX thing, is it a visual component to be embedded in an AX form?

Answer (score 2):

For an overview of COM integration look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa591337.aspx

For an overview of .Net integration look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa659581.aspx

Answer (score 1):

the "target"-application, with which i want to interact is a stand-alone exe with COM-functionality.
as i know, COM isn't ( or will not be ) supported in AX 2009 - therefore .net should be used.
if i understand your answer correctly, it's just the other one round!
the dll just works as a wrapper to access the application mentioned above.
regsvr32 don't work with the dll, since regasm must be used to register.
i've also added a reference in the AOT - no change.
curious thing is - it has already worked, and is still working on my local dev system. but not on other systems.

Comment: COM+ is supported by AX 2009, but it may not be in future versions.

Comment: I still have not got a clue how your "target"-application and AX is supposed to work together. What is the "main" application, what type of communication is needed between the two.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved.
everything was correct - only misleading thing was the error-message launching a form with the activeX-component added, telling "component not found on system..."

it was a totally different error in the activeX code:
parsing a xml-document with a special character in it and without defining the correct iso-encoding in the xml-file had thrown an error not catched. this(!!) caused all further problems and the crash-bug mentioned in the initial post :/

thanks anyway for help.